# Is it spelled "propeling" or "propelling" in American English?

Tags: american-english, orthography, doubled-consonants

Since *travel* becomes *traveler* and *traveling* in AmE (no double **l**), I thought that the same rule applied to *propel*.

However, reading and writing *propeling* feels awkward. (And *propeler* feels even more awkward...)

What is the correct spelling in American English?

(Google <del>seems to</del> **definitely** favors *propelling*, but I thought it best to ask the experts.)

Comment: The same goes to "expel" and "repel".
e.g. "Expeller pressed extra virgin coconut oil is your best choice."
"This material is water repellent."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/) (1990–2011) and the [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) (1810s–2000s):

```
             COCA   COHA

propelling    425    363
propeling       0      0
propeller     782    981
propeler        0      0
```

The general rule, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants), is:

> The final consonant of an English word is sometimes doubled in both American and British spelling when adding a suffix beginning with a vowel [...]. Generally, this occurs only when the word's final syllable is stressed and when it also ends with a single vowel followed by a single consonant. **In British English, however, a final -l is often doubled even when the final syllable is unstressed. This exception is no longer usual in American English**, apparently because of Noah Webster.

Emphasis added.

Comment: It is worth adding that this also goes for other resonants than l: stressed _program_ -> _programmed_ vs. unstressed _fathom_ -> _fathomed_; _begin_ -> _beginner_ vs. _reckon_ -> _reckoner_; _occur_ -> _occurring_ vs. _succour_ -> _succouring_.

Answer (score 4):

The rule as I have heard it says that AmE does not double the vowel *when the syllable is unstressed*. Since "propel" has final stress, that rule does not apply.

[I am not a speaker of AmE].