# Why is "fulfil" spelt as "fulfill" in American English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, doubled-consonants

In [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9853/), simplification is stated as one reason for spelling variations in American English. But unlike in *color* and *favorite*, the number of letters to spell the word in *fulfil* increases in American English.

Other than for "creating a distinct" variant, is there any reason for the change? Going by [the etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fulfill&allowed_in_frame=0) the ideal spelling should be *fullfill*, so even that may be not a motivation.

Comment: In American English, "spelt" is a rarely seen and strikingly unnatural (though correct) spelling of the past participle of "spell".  A more common spelling would be "spelled".

Comment: I am American.  If I see *spelt* I think of a certain kind of wheat sometimes sold as "health food".

Comment: And in American English, *spelt* is also a strikingly unnatural pronunciation of the past participle.

Comment: @Pantalones To paraphrase [Ambrose Bierce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrose_Bierce), english.se is God's way of teaching Americans spelling :)

Comment: I didn't even notice the word _spelt_ because, to me (non-US), it is spelt correctly!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Interesting question :) Reading up on this has been a pretty crazy experience. My conclusions are the following:

- The reason for the change from [*fulfil*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fulfil) to [*fulfill*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fulfill) is attributed to [inflection](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inflection), with the spelling modified to suit the function of the word.
- The reason why it isn't spelt *fullfill* is similar to why *parallel* only retains the single 'l' at the end—to curb the apparent fugliness of an '-llell' cluster in words such as *unparalleled* etc.
- There is also a question of consistency involved.

But, unfortunately, another rule in the AE transition was to preserve the "base" word as much as possible, which is why *skill*/_skilful in BE became *skill*/*skillful* in AE. However, this introduced a cluster of letters in words such as *skillfully*. To put it mildly, the result of exercise was and remains consistently inconsistent.

A related question on the difference in the AE/BE [spellings of *propelling*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20487/is-it-spelled-propeling-or-propelling-in-american-english?rq=1) covers similar territory. It also points to a WP page detailing the [differences between American and British spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants) which includes the following section on the madness of doubled consonants:

> - The word parallel keeps a single -l- in British English, as in American English (paralleling, unparalleled), to avoid the unappealing
>     cluster -llell-.
> - Words with two vowels before a final l are also spelled with -ll- in British English before a suffix when the first vowel either acts as
>     a consonant (equalling and initialled; in the United States, equaling
>     or initialed), or belongs to a separate syllable (British fu•el•ling
>     and di•alled; American fu•el•ing and di•aled).
>
>   - British woollen is a further exception due to the double vowel (American: woolen). Also, wooly is accepted in American English,
>       though woolly prevails in both systems.

There's also a note on *-ful* and *-fil*:

> In both American and British usages, words normally spelled -ll
>   usually drop the second l when used as prefixes or suffixes, for
>   example full→useful, handful; all→almighty, altogether; well→welfare,
>   welcome; chill→chilblain. The British fulfil and American fulfill are
>   never fullfill or fullfil. Johnson wavered on this issue. His
>   dictionary of 1755 lemmatises distil and instill, downhil and uphill.

Comment: Just looked up "fugliness". Wish I hadn't. :-)

Comment: @urbycoz The proverbial slip of the tongue there ... but hey, anything that gets people looking things up gets a +1 in my book ;)

Answer (score -2):

Not so much an answer, but I was brought up to consider that a second vowel (particularly an "e") after a vowel-consonant combination changes the pronunciation of the first vowel, thus

initial -> initialled ok
initial -> initialed not ok

as this second case would be pronounced "initial-Ale-d" rather than "initial-ud". This is perhaps somewhat related to for instance the word "impaled", so clearly the "-aled" construct has one use case.